# stat_bin reverting to default

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am having a bit of a hard time getting my histogram to plot the correct number of bins. I would like each bin to be the values 1-5, 5-10, 10-15, etc but when I use stat_bin it reverts to the range/30 default.

```
ggplot(tmp,aes(x = values)) + 
+     facet_wrap(~ind) +
+     geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)),stat="bin")+
+     scale_x_continuous("Percent above 30x")+
+     scale_y_continuous("Fraction of panel")+
+     opts(title = yz)+
+     stat_bin(bandwidth=5.0)
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
```

I was thinking it would likely be some silly syntax thing that I did not quite grasp while I was reading.
I was hoping someone could advise me on why this is happening.

Comment: Please don't add answers inside your question. I'll remove your answer and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP posted this solution: add `binwidth=5` argument to `geom`.

```
ggplot(tmp,aes(x = values)) +
    facet_wrap(~ind) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)), binwidth=5)+
    scale_x_continuous("Percent above 30x")+
    scale_y_continuous("Fraction of panel")+
    opts(title = yz)
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have enough rep to answer my own questions until 8 hours after or something

Comment: @user If you want to post your own answer after the expiry time, let me know and I'll delete this answer. (Simply add a comment to this answer, and I'll get notified.)